# About cakePHP's controller access

Tags: php, cakephp

How to access a page by the way : 
`http://test.loc?controller=a&action=b&id=123`, 
I read the cakePHP's document ,and not find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a controller you should follow cakephp syntax :
your Domain Name / if any plugin exists then plugin name / controller name/action
like this:

```
www.example.com/user_management/users/add
```

here user_management is plugin name 
users is controller name 
add is action name

According to you, you are using query string
Your url should be

```
http://test.loc/a/b/123
```

Comment: Is there any way to access the controller like this : http://test.loc?controller=a&action=b&id=123

Comment: No you cannot access through query string.

Comment: Technically there is, but one would have to at least use a custom dispatcher or controller factory filter (depending on the CakePHP version) and route class... all in all, not an overly good idea.

Comment: Yes you can manage this through custom distpatcher but that is not good